# Regex javascript password

Tags: javascript, regex

Buenas tengo este patrón creado

```
/^(?=.*[a-zñ])(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉIÓÚ])(?=.*\d){2,4}(?=.*[\$\/\.])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\$\/\.\d]{7,15}(?=.*\d$)/;
```

Y debo controlar esto: tamaño 8,16, caracteres alfabéticos 2 mínimo, con una mayús, con caractéres con acento, 4 números máx y 2 mín, debe terminar en un número y obligatorio caracteres como $,.,/,*;#,!,..

¿Qué tengo mal?

Comment: Bienvenida cual es el error que te esta dando?

Comment: @Ruth no entiendo por qué estás insistiendo en empeorar tu pregunta. Hacerla más corta de esta forma no la hace mejor, todo lo contrario, sin mencionar que el título en inglés y tan poco descriptivo no es recomendable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Qué tengo mal?

1. No estás controlando el largo máximo:

   Eliminemos las inspecciones (lookaheads), y veamos:

   ```
   [a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ\$\/\.\d]{7,15}(?=.*\d$)
   ```

   El `.*` hace que pueda haber cualquier cantidad de caracteres desde el último repetido en la clase de caracteres hasta el `\d$` del final.

   En cambio, mucho más sencillo:

   ```
   [a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$/.\d]{7,15}\d$
   ```

   - No hace falta escapar `$`, `*`, `/`, `.`, etc. dentro de una clase (no tienen significado especial ahí).
2. Al menos una mayúscula: no estás incluyendo a las mayúsculas acentuadas en
   `(?=.*[A-ZÑ])`, pero supongo que es intencional.
3. Contener un carácter con acento. En `(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉIÓÚ])` te faltó el acento en la `Í` (y supongo que `üÜ` no van).
4. 4 dígitos como máximo y como mínimo 2... Este es un error importante para que entiendas. Estás usando:

   ```
   (?=.*\d){2,4}
   ```

   Pero tené en cuenta que en una inspección (*lookaround*), luego de intentar la coincidencia, el cursor vuelve a la posición en la que estaba antes de intentarlo (en este caso al inicio del string). Cuando se repite una inspección, en realidad, se está preguntando (2 a 4 veces) si hay 1 dígito desde el inicio del string...

   Si no se entendió:

   - Hay **1** dígito desde el inicio del string... Sí
   - Hay **1** dígito desde el inicio del string... Sí
   - Hay **1** dígito desde el inicio del string... Sí
   - Hay **1** dígito desde el inicio del string... Sí -Déjà vu :-)

   En ningún momento estás viendo si hay 2 a 4 dígitos en todo el string.

   Para ver que haya exclusivamente entre 2 y 4, tenemos que repetirlo adentro de la inspección:

   ```
   ^(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}$)
   ```
5. La condición "*caracteres alfabéticos (2 como mínimo)*" no la estás comprobando en ningún lado. Sería:

   ```
   ^(?=(?:[^A-Za-záéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]*[A-Za-záéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]){2})
   ```
6. Usaste `(?=.*[a-zñ])` pero no mencionaste que tenía que tener una minúscula en tus reglas.

**En definitiva:**

```
/^(?=(?:[^A-Za-záéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]*[A-Za-záéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]){2})(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}$)(?=.*[$/.])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$/.\d]{7,15}\d$/
```

**Simplifiquemos**

Pero vayamos más a fondo. Por un lado dijiste:

1. Una mayúscula + una letra acentuada.

Y además:

2. 2 caracteres alfabéticos

No hay forma que se cumpla la primera y no la segunda. Si tiene una mayúscula y 1 letra acentuada, evidentemente tiene 2 caracteres alfabéticos... podemos eliminar una condición:

```
/^(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}$)(?=.*[$/.])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$/.\d]{7,15}\d$/
```

Y sabemos que tiene que terminar con 1 dígito, ya lo estamos controlando en

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}$)
```

Podemos eliminar la condición de `\d$` al final

```
/^(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}$)(?=.*[$/.])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$/.\d]{8,16}$/
```

---

Demo:

```css
input { width: 30ch;  padding: 0.5em 1ch; border: 5px solid red;  }
input:valid { border: 5px solid green;  }
```

```html
<input pattern="(?=.*[A-ZÑ])(?=.*[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ])(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}$)(?=.*[$/.])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ$/.\d]{8,16}"
        placeholder="Validación de contraseña"
        required>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tus explicaciones son la caña, eres un crack. Gracias al fin llego a entender todo. Un saludo.